# UIScrollView don't go all over the screen when trying to pin it to the bottom of the superview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiscrollview

I'm trying to fix keyboard content covering bug with UIScrollView in my simple learning app. Keyboard didn't cover my textfield, but it covered my other content. So I have textfield at the bottom of the screen, and I placed UIScrollView underneath. 
I set the following constraints to scrollview:

```
Scroll View.top = TextField.bottom +5
trailing = Scroll View.trailing
leading = Scroll View.leading
Bottom Layout Guide.top = Scroll View.bottom
```

And inside scrollview I have UIView with all my content. That UIView is pinned to scroll view's edges (leading, trailing, top and bottom) and have equal width with View.
So it looks fine on 4 inch display, like so:
[iPhone 4 inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gmNwG.png)

But on bigger screen it don't go all over the screen. Here is the screenshot:
[iPhone 5.5 inch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAn2X.png)

It gets even worse on iPad. So I don't get any idea why this weird things are happened. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen issues like this when you dealt with autolayout. I would recommend you to check below points.

1. Please check whether scrollview contentsize is equal to height of UIView inside the scrollview.
2. Make sure you have constraints in all the UIcomponenents inside the scrollview.
3. Also check whether any height constraints are present in scrollview or inner container View/tableview i.e. explicitly set height contraints in tablview height etc.
4. UIView bottom constraint to scrollview should be **equal to** property.
5. Enable exception breakpoint in xcode project and check whether you get any autolayout expception in xcode console while running the app.

Comment: Thanks you for your answer!
I just tried to delete all constraints for UIView that was inside of UIScrollView, and set new constraints:
Equal width and equal height to scroll view;
Align X and Y centers to scrollView.
And this worked. So problem is solved.